# How to type an array of objects that could be empty in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I would expect typescript to throw an error if you're accessing a property on an array item that could be `undefined`. For example:

```js
const arr: {foo: string}[] = []
arr[0].foo // I would expect a ts error here
```

Maybe this is a limitation of typescript since it can't know the length of an array at build time? If so, is there a more strict way to type this so that `arr[0].foo` throws an error?

Comment: The issue is that `Array` has a numeric index signature, which are implicitly expected to always be defined for any numeric index.  You can either use `({foo: string} | undefined)[]` or enable `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, as mentioned in the linked q/a.